# How to resolve a string parameter to mapped integers in XQuery?

Tags: string, integer, mapping, xquery

I need to map to a parameter in an XQuery function an integer value instead of a string. For example:

- Parameter1 has the value `value1` and I have to replace it with the integer `1`
- Parameter2 has the value `value2` and I have to replace it with the integer `2`

Comment: Variables in XQuery are immutable. i.e.: Once a value is assigned to a variable, it cannot be reassigned.

Comment: ok, but if I put everything in a switch I can return an integer based on the string received?

Comment: Yes, however `switch` is only available in XQuery 3.0.

Comment: the alternative for 1.0 version is only the if..else clause ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different options, depending on the XQuery version you can use.

Given you generally need to resolve `valueN` to `N`, simply do `substring-after($value, 'value')`. In the following, I assume it's not that easy and replaced `1`, `2`, ... by letters, to prevent such "easy" solutions. You can return integers instead of the strings for any of the examples.

## XQuery 1.0 compatible

### if-then-else-chains

Probably very obvious.

```
let $value := 'value1'
return
  if ($value eq 'value1')
  then 'A'
  else
    if ($value eq 'value2')
    then 'B'
    else 'default'
```

### Looking up in an XML snippet

Define an XML structure, which you subsequently query for the value. If necessary, add `/string()` to get the string value of the node instead of the `<value/>` element.

```
let $map :=
  <values>
    <value id="value1">A</value>
    <value id="value2">B</value>
  </values>
let $value := 'value1'
return
  $map/value[@id=$value]
```

### Looking up in a sequence

A similar solution can be applied for sequences instead of the outer `<values/>` element, of course:

```
let $map := (
  <value id="value1">A</value>,
  <value id="value2">B</value>
)
let $value := 'value1'
return
  $map[@id=$value]
```

## XQuery 3.0 only

### Using switch statements

Switch statements are a very elegant way for a bunch of fixed values. Extracting to a function might increase readability.

```
let $value := 'value1'
return
  switch ($value)
  case 'value1' return 'A'
  case 'value2' return 'B'
  default return 'default'
```

### Using maps

If supported, XQuery maps are a very powerful feature, which can also be used to look up values.

```
let $map := map {
  'value1': 'A',
  'value2': 'B'
}
let $value := 'value1'
return
  $map($value)
```